# AngularJS - plotting points on a map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plot

I am new to AngularJS and I am looking to add some plotting functionality to my web app.

I have a map of the world (a png file) and X/Y coordinates that I want to overlay on top of the map image.  For example, my data might look like:

```
[
    {
        'location_x':'123',
        'location_y':'224',
        'date':'20100505',
        'text':'I loved this place!'
    },
    {
        'location_x':'222',
        'location_y':'333',
        'date':'20110606',
        'text':'Never again!'
    }
]
```

I would like the date values to appear in the area designated by the x/y coordinates, and the text to appear as a tooltip for the date.

I do not need the application to expose the capability to edit the x/y coordinates, I only need to display the values that my data source gives me.  I need to use a custom image as the map.  What are my options for getting this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [LeafletJS](http://leafletjs.com/) .

Another option is to use the [Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?hl=nl).

Comment: Will either of these work with my own map image?  These look awesome, but for my use case I need to use a specific png file for my map.